# the relation between activity and fragment in android

Tags: android

When we create a fragment , we must have an activity (which is created and exist) , but i have found In Fragment life cycle `onActivityCreated` method , which is give me an idea , that the fragment created first,  then the activity ,which is does not make sense , so could anyone explain the misunderstanding here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

onActivityCreated is called when the Activity's onCreate is finished.  It tells you the activity is fully initialized and capable of being used.  If you have need to access Activity variables that are initialized in onCreate of the Activity, you can safely do it in onActivityCreated.

Comment: So  can i conclude two things : the first thing is that  onActivityCreated does not accure after onCreate of the Fragment ? and the secone thin is the creation of the fragmetn/fragments and activity/activites does not accure in  a sequential order , but in 'parallel' and the OS 'rearrange' those elements ?

Comment: No, it happens after onCreate of the Fragment.  However onCreate of the fragment may happen during onCreate of the Activity, especially if the Fragment is in the layout.  onActivityCreated is promised to only be called after onCreate of the Activity.

Comment: that's make sense now , but what you mean by "Fragment in the layout ?"

Comment: If your fragment is defined in the layout xml file set by the Activity via setContentView.

Comment: but may Fragment and activity created together even fragment is not in the layout ?

Comment: @Learner : Don't confuse 'created' with 'fully intialised and running'. You can create the basic 'shell' of a `Fragment` using `new` but it's in a dormant non-functional state. It's not usable until it is attached to an `Activity` (using a `FragmentTransaction`) and goes through the startup phase of its life-cycle. If one of the first things an `Activity` does is create and add the `Fragment` but then does some other things in its `onCreate` method, the `onActivityCreated` method of the `Fragment` won't be called until the `Activity` `onCreate` method has completed.

Comment: @GabeSechan : "...the activity is fully initialized and capable of being used." - Not technically true but I understand what you mean to say. The `Activity` will still have to go through the 'start' and 'resume' phases of its life-cycle before it is fully initialised and enters the running state.

Comment: @Squonk Depends on how you define initialized.  onStart is called when some portion of it is on screen and onResume called when it becomes the foreground app.  The activity is running and can be doing work before that.  Some activities in 3rd party libraries never even show a UI so ignore start and resume.

Comment: @GabeSechan : All Activities go through the same life-cycle (creation, start, resume, running, pause, stop, destruction). Even if you don't override the life-cycle methods the base methods are called implicitly by the Android OS. As for 3rd party libraries with Activities which have no UI - remind me to avoid them - an Activity is basically an intelligent UI framework. Don't get me wrong, I wasn't criticising - it's just that it's most common for at least `onResume` to be used in an Activity and until that is complete it hasn't properly reached a 'running' state.

Comment: @Squonk Yes, but its also generally accepted that all variables should be initialized in onCreate, as it will only be called once (onStart may be called multiple times).  So after onCreate the app is generally initialized.  onStart and onResume should only be user to start battery draining work that you want to turn off when not on screen  As for 3rd party with UI-less activities-  start with AdMob.  Its not that uncommon, if an app wants to run its own isolated process.

Comment: @GabeSechan : But a quote from your answer... "If you have need to access Activity variables that are initialized in onCreate of the Activity, you can safely do it in onActivityCreated." - A `Fragment` should be modular, self-contained and re-usable. It should never know what type of `Activity` it is attached to or presume the `Activity` has any specific variables or methods that can be directly accessed. If you break that model then you may as well just ditch `Fragments` altogether and stick with all code being in discrete `Activities`.